# Scraping Spotify Top 200 streaming data with R

Tags: r, spotify, rvest

novice R user here. I'm looking to scrape a large amount of data on daily streaming volumes on songs that are on Spotify's Top 200 charts for a research project I am involved with. Basically, I would like to write a script to scrape all info for tracks in the top 200 on a given day, such as [today's chart](https://charts.spotify.com/charts/view/regional-global-daily/latest), and have this done for every day for a number of years, across a number of countries. I used some code from a guide that I followed previously to successfully scrape said data, but it is now not working for me.

I previously followed [this guide](https://rpubs.com/argdata/web_scraping) pretty much word for word. While this originally worked, it now returns an empty tibble. I suspect that the problem may have to do with the fact that Spotify have re-developed their charts site since my last attempt. The site is different in appearance, but importantly the html node names appear to be different as well. My hunch is that this is what is causing the issue.

However, I am not at all sure if this is the case. Would appreciate it greatly if I could have some guidance on what I would need to do differently to achieve my aims, and whether it is indeed still possible to scrape these charts.

Cheers

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. This is a bit of a high level ("how do I do this project") question for stack overflow, so you may find it gets closed - questions with single specific issues to solve are usually better received.  My advice would be to break your code down a step at a time and test each step one after the other (can I access the web page, does it download any data, is it the right data etc etc), but without much more information I don't think anyone can give you more specific advice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.